# I am getting error when trying to add phone authentication in my Android app project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, authentication, android-authenticator

I am trying to add phone no. authentication in my new video app (I already have Facebook and Google authentication in my app) and they are working well. I need to save and parse user data in the server and in local as well.

I do not know much about phone number authentication, please help me to fix the issue in phone no. authentication.

As I already said Facebook and Google authentication are working perfectly and user data from these is also saving in local and server as well.

Please make phone no. authentication work like google or Facebook.

Note - **Phone no. authentication** is working perfectly but the data is not storing in server and local. (phone no. authentication is storing in Firebase but not on server).

When I put phone no. it authenticates successfully but then app says "App is stopped" other than going to "main_menu".

Please help me ... I am in trouble\

Code of login_A where google and facebook authentication takes place, I added a button here which sends me to login_Activity where phone authentication takes place.

```
public class Login_A extends Activity {

    private ImageView PhoneLogin_btn;


    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    IOSDialog iosDialog;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    View top_view;

    TextView login_title_txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 26) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
        }

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        this.getWindow()
                .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // if the user is already login trought facebook then we will logout the user automatically
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        iosDialog = new IOSDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setSpinnerClockwise(false)
                .setMessageContentGravity(Gravity.END)
                .build();

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);

        findViewById(R.id.facebook_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Loginwith_FB();
            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.google_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sign_in_with_gmail();
            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.Goback).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

         top_view=findViewById(R.id.top_view);



        login_title_txt=findViewById(R.id.login_title_txt);
        login_title_txt.setText("You need a "+getString(R.string.app_name)+"\naccount to Continue");

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("By signing up, you confirm that you agree to our \n Terms of Use and have read and understood \n our Privacy Policy.");
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Open_Privacy_policy();
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 99, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_terms_condition_txt);
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        printKeyHash();

        // related to phone login
        PhoneLogin_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_btn);
        PhoneLogin_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivityPhoneLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivityPhoneLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void Open_Privacy_policy() {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Variables.privacy_policy));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(200);
        top_view.startAnimation(anim);
        top_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_top, R.anim.out_from_bottom);
    }

    // Bottom two function are related to Fb implementation
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    //facebook implementation
    public void Loginwith_FB() {

        LoginManager.getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(Login_A.this,
                        Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));

        // initialze the facebook sdk and request to facebook for login
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()  {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.d("resp_token",loginResult.getAccessToken()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("resp",""+error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Login Error"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(final AccessToken token) {
        // if user is login then this method will call and
        // facebook will return us a token which will user for get the info of user
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        Log.d("resp_token",token.getToken()+"");
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            iosDialog.show();
                             final String id = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                                    Log.d("resp",user.toString());
                                    //after get the info of user we will pass to function which will store the info in our server

                                    String fname=""+user.optString("first_name");
                                    String lname=""+user.optString("last_name");


                                    if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                                        fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                                    if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                                        lname="";

                                    Call_Api_For_Signup(""+id,fname
                                            ,lname,
                                            "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?width=500&width=500",
                                            "facebook");

                                }
                            });

                            // here is the request to facebook sdk for which type of info we have required
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "last_name,first_name,email");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(Login_A.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        if(requestCode==123){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
        else if(mCallbackManager!=null)
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    // Google implementation
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    public void Sign_in_with_gmail(){
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(Login_A.this);
        if (account != null) {
            String id=account.getId();
            String fname=""+account.getGivenName();
            String lname=""+account.getFamilyName();

            String pic_url;

            if(account.getPhotoUrl()!=null) {
                 pic_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            } else {
                pic_url="null";
            }

            if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

            if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                lname="User";
            Call_Api_For_Signup(id,fname,lname,pic_url,"gmail");
        }
        else {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 123);
        }
    }

    // Relate to google login
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) {
                String id=account.getId();
                String fname=""+account.getGivenName();
                String lname=""+account.getFamilyName();

                // if we do not get the picture of user then we will use default profile picture

                String pic_url;

                if (account.getPhotoUrl()!=null) {
                    pic_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                } else {
                    pic_url="null";
                }

                if(fname.equals("") || fname.equals("null"))
                    fname=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

                if(lname.equals("") || lname.equals("null"))
                    lname="";

                Call_Api_For_Signup(id,fname,lname,pic_url,"gmail");


            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("Error message", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    // this function call an Api for Signin
    public void Call_Api_For_Signup(String id,
                                    String f_name,
                                    String l_name,
                                    String picture,
                                    String singnup_type) {


        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo =getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String appversion=packageInfo.versionName;

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
        try {

            parameters.put("fb_id", id);
            parameters.put("first_name",""+f_name);
            parameters.put("last_name", ""+l_name);
            parameters.put("profile_pic",picture);
            parameters.put("gender","m");
            parameters.put("version",appversion);
            parameters.put("signup_type",singnup_type);
            parameters.put("device",Variables.device);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iosDialog.show();
        ApiRequest.Call_Api(this, Variables.SignUp, parameters, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void Responce(String resp) {
                iosDialog.cancel();
                Parse_signup_data(resp);

            }
        });

    }




    // if the signup successfull then this method will call and it store the user info in local
    public void Parse_signup_data(String loginData){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);
            String code=jsonObject.optString("code");
            if(code.equals("200")){
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
                JSONObject userdata = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Variables.u_id,userdata.optString("fb_id"));
                editor.putString(Variables.f_name,userdata.optString("first_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.l_name,userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_name,userdata.optString("first_name")+" "+userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.gender,userdata.optString("gender"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_pic,userdata.optString("profile_pic"));
                editor.putString(Variables.api_token,userdata.optString("tokon"));
                editor.putBoolean(Variables.islogin,true);
                editor.commit();

                Variables.sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                Variables.user_id=Variables.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.u_id,"");

                top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));



            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+jsonObject.optString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    // this function will print the keyhash of your project
    // which is very helpful during Fb login implementation
    public void printKeyHash()  {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName() , PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for(Signature signature:info.signatures)
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("keyhash" , Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
'''
 below is the code of Login_A which is phone authentication]


''' public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private EditText mCountryCode;
    private EditText mPhoneNumber;

    private Button mGenerateBtn;
    private ProgressBar mLoginProgress;

    private TextView mLoginFeedbackText;
    private EditText phoneLogin;
    IOSDialog iosDialog;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    View top_view;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phone_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        mCountryCode = findViewById(R.id.country_code_text);
        mPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phone_number_text);
        mGenerateBtn = findViewById(R.id.generate_btn);
        mLoginProgress = findViewById(R.id.login_progress_bar);
        mLoginFeedbackText = findViewById(R.id.login_form_feedback);

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);


        mGenerateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String country_code = mCountryCode.getText().toString();
                String phone_number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

                String complete_phone_number = "+" + country_code + phone_number;

                if(country_code.isEmpty() || phone_number.isEmpty()){
                    mLoginFeedbackText.setText("Please fill in the form to continue.");
                    mLoginFeedbackText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mGenerateBtn.setEnabled(false);

                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            complete_phone_number,
                            60,
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                            LoginActivity.this,
                            mCallbacks
                    );

                }
            }
        });

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                mLoginFeedbackText.setText("Verification Failed, please try again.");
                mLoginFeedbackText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mGenerateBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(final String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent otpIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OtpActivity.class);
                            otpIntent.putExtra("AuthCredentials", s);
                            startActivity(otpIntent);
                        }
                    },
                10000);
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mCurrentUser != null){
            sendUserToHome();
        }
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            sendUserToHome();
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                mLoginFeedbackText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mLoginFeedbackText.setText("There was an error verifying OTP");
                            }
                        }
                        mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mGenerateBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendUserToHome() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);


        String id = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String fname = "" + "nishant456";
        String lname = "" + "67474";
        String pic_url = "" + "null";
        Login_A callApi = new Login_A();
        Call_Api_For_Signup(id,fname,lname,pic_url,"phone");

        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);





        finish();
    }

    // this function call an Api for Signin
    public void Call_Api_For_Signup(String id,
                                    String f_name,
                                    String l_name,
                                    String picture,
                                    String singnup_type) {


        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo =getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String appversion=packageInfo.versionName;

        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
        try {

            parameters.put("fb_id", id);
            parameters.put("first_name",""+f_name);
            parameters.put("last_name", ""+l_name);
            parameters.put("profile_pic",picture);
            parameters.put("gender","m");
            parameters.put("version",appversion);
            parameters.put("signup_type",singnup_type);
            parameters.put("device", Variables.device);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iosDialog.show();
        ApiRequest.Call_Api(this, Variables.SignUp, parameters, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void Responce(String resp) {
                iosDialog.cancel();
                Parse_signup_data(resp);

            }
        });

    }




    // if the signup successfull then this method will call and it store the user info in local
    public void Parse_signup_data(String loginData){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);
            String code=jsonObject.optString("code");
            if(code.equals("200")){
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
                JSONObject userdata = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Variables.u_id,userdata.optString("fb_id"));
                editor.putString(Variables.f_name,userdata.optString("first_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.l_name,userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_name,userdata.optString("first_name")+" "+userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.gender,userdata.optString("gender"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_pic,userdata.optString("profile_pic"));
                editor.putString(Variables.api_token,userdata.optString("tokon"));
                editor.putBoolean(Variables.islogin,true);
                editor.apply();

                Variables.sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                Variables.user_id=Variables.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.u_id,"");

                top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));



            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+jsonObject.optString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: There is **way** too much code here for us to efficiently help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to increase the chances that someone can help. In addition, if your app crashes there will be an error message and stack trace in its logcat output. Find those and add them to your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given any id to the top_view. You are using top_view before starting MainMenuActivity in the LoginActivity class. This might me one of the reason for the app to stop.