# phone. no. login is working in android but the data is not storing on server and api as well

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication

I am trying to add phone no. authentication in my new video app( I already have Facebook and Google authentication in my app) and they are working well. I need to save and parse user data in the server and in local as well.

I do not know much about phone number authentication, please help me to fix the issue in phone no. authentication.

As I already said Facebook and google authentication working perfectly and user data from these is also saving in local and server as well.

Please make phone no. authentication work like google or Facebook.

Note - Phone no. authentication is working perfectly but the data is not storing in server and local. (phone no. authentication is storing in Firebase but not on server).

when I put phone no. it authenticates successfully but then app says "App is stopped" other than going to "main_menu".

please help me ... I am in trouble

here is the link of question where I added code with question.....please check it

[i am getting error when trying to add phone authentication in my android app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323174/i-am-getting-error-when-trying-to-add-phone-authentication-in-my-android-app-pro)

Comment: please add code and logcat?

Comment: here is the link of question where I added code with question....../.


please check it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323174/i-am-getting-error-when-trying-to-add-phone-authentication-in-my-android-app-pro

Comment: please help me in finding the error.   please .....